# Why is this system non-linear?

Tags: coding-theory

A simple recursive convolutional code $g_1(D)\in GF^2$

\begin{equation}
g_{1}(D) = \frac{1}{1\oplus D}
\end{equation}

is cascaded with $g_2(D)\in \mathbb{R}$

\begin{equation}
g_{2}(D) = 1-D
\end{equation}

to give an overall transfer function

\begin{equation}
g_{c}(D) = \frac{1-D}{1 \oplus D}
\end{equation}

Although the two systems $g_1{D}$ and $g_2(D)$ are linear individually, it is claimed that $g_c(D)$ is not. 
Can please someone suggest why is that the case?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to cascade two filters defined in different domains...

Comment: You are correct. Generally one would not do that. But I found the cascade of these two filters in a research paper for a particular application. What I don't understand is the claim made in paper that the cascade of these two linear systems is not linear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has more to do with engineering than mathematics. For your
first filter, the input is a sequence of elements of $\mathbb F_2$ 
which an engineer treats as real numbers $0$ and $1$. The recursive
filter output is also a sequence of elements of $\mathbb F_2$ but
the engineer has effectively transformed 
$$y_n = x_n + y_{n-1} = x_n \oplus y_{n-1} ~\quad~ \text{equation in } \mathbb F_2$$
into
$$y_{n} = x_{n} + y_{n-1} - 2x_{n}y_{n-1}~~\qquad \text{equation in } \mathbb R$$
The second filter sets
$$z_n = y_{n} - y_{n-1}~~\qquad\text{equation in } \mathbb R$$
but notice that the output can take on values in $\{-1, 0, +1\}$
and so the overall cascade is not a linear filter regardless of
whether an engineer or a mathematician is looking at it.

Comment: Isn't  $y_n = (x_n-y_{n-1})^2$ sufficient to conclude that the system is non-linear? I didn't understand how output$\in \{-1,0,1\}$ can lead to saying that system is non-linear. Can you please comment on this

Comment: Yes, it is straightforward to show that the cascade is nonlinear over $\mathbb R$. That the output is not a linear function over $\mathbb F_2$ of the input is seen from the fact that the output is not even _in_ $\mathbb F_2$.